How to get the string prefixed with "Mat" within curly braces {} and add a comma to output
How to get the string prefixed with "Mat" within curly braces {} and print with the addition of a comma?
e.g.
in:
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

out:
MatSidenavModule,
MatToolbarModule,

I tried:
awk -F"[{}]" 'BEGIN {/Mat/} {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2","}' in

GNU Awk version is 5.0.1.

The BEGIN block should contain code which you want to run before the main script. I'm guessing you want
awk -F"[{}]" '/Mat/ {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2","}' in

A more precise condition would be $2 ~ /Mat/ to ensure that you don't trigger on stray matches in other fields (or even use /^[ \t]*Mat/ if you always expect it to match at the beginning of the field).
awk -F"[{}]" '$2 ~ /^[ \t]*Mat/ {
    gsub(/[ \t]+/, "", $2);
    print $2 ","}' in

Using Awk for this sort of thing basically requires the input to use predictable formatting, and not e.g. arbitrarily add a newline after import {. In the limit, you need a parser for the language you are processing (Javascript?)

Using any awk:
$ awk -F' *[{}] *' -v ORS=',\n' '$2 ~ /^Mat/{ print $2 }' file
MatSidenavModule,
MatToolbarModule,


With your shown samples please try following awk using its match function with regex \{ Mat[^}]*
awk '
match($0,/\{ Mat[^}]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2) ","
}
' Input_file


I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

then
awk '{sub(/.*{ /,"");sub(/ }.*/,",")}/^Mat/' file.txt

gives output
MatSidenavModule,
MatToolbarModule,

Explanation: I replace everything up to {  with empty string and  } and everything after it using ,. Then I check if line now starts with Mat and if it so default action i.e. print is undertaken. Such arrangement prevent false-positives if Mat is present anywhere outside { }, though it still will print if line starts with Mat and has not curly brackets.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

{ is a regexp metachar that starts a repetition interval. It's undefined what that does after another repetition metachar (*) and it's also undefined what it does if not immediately followed by a digit. You should use /.*\{.../ instead of /.*{.../ to get defined, portable behavior that's also guaranteed to work in future releases of gawk.
